# Filezilla connection debugging

Tags: connection, filezilla

I know this question is too broad to answer, but I can't connect to a filezilla server I'm hosting.

The computer its on has a real IP address (not not).

I am allowing connections on ports 21 and 22.

I can connect from a local filezilla client over both ftp (mapped to port 21) and ftps (mapped to port 22).

Whenever I try to connect from another computer, nothing happens.

When I connect to a website hosted on the same computer (over http or https) the connection works fine.

The client just hangs and the server doesn't print any new lines, as if it has detected no connection at all.

How can I debug this problem? It seems too broad to really ask about, so how do I go about testing to improve the situation?

Answer (score 0):

try telneting to the port :

`telnet HOST 21`

if you get any response, it should be from a ftp server.